# Error executing script RunApp: : Error starting Sun's native2ascii: 

Tags: eclipse, grails, java

when i switch to a new workspace i was facing this error.

i know that this error because oh jdk, but i try to:

1- add  jdk1.6.0_25
2- add java-6-openjdk

to my windows>preferences>java>installed JREs but error didn't solve

hint:
1- my OS is Linux mint
2- my eclipse is Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.(Indigo Release)
3- grails version grails 1.3.7

please tell me in details how can i solve this problem

thanks in advance

```
[native2ascii] Converting 1 file from /home/danny/danny_Source/danny.com/
 grails- app/i18n to /home/danny/.grails/1.3.7/projects/danny.com/resources/grails-app/i18n
 Error executing script RunApp: : Error starting Sun's native2ascii: 
 : Error starting Sun's native2ascii: 
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:391)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: : Error starting Sun's native2ascii: 
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.native2ascii.SunNative2Ascii.run(
SunNative2Ascii.java:67)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.native2ascii.DefaultNative2Ascii.convert(DefaultNative2Ascii.java:54)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Native2Ascii.convert(Native2Ascii.java:268)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Native2Ascii.execute(Native2Ascii.java:227)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure13.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:116)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure13.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:115)
at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp:28)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.tools.native2ascii.Main
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:156)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:128)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.native2ascii.SunNative2Ascii.run(SunNative2Ascii.java:51)
... 22 more
--- Nested Exception ---
: Error starting Sun's native2ascii: 
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.native2ascii.SunNative2Ascii.run(SunNative2Ascii.java:67)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.native2ascii.DefaultNative2Ascii.convert(DefaultNative2Ascii.java:54)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Native2Ascii.convert(Native2Ascii.java:268)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Native2Ascii.execute(Native2Ascii.java:227)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure13.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:116)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure13.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:115)
at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp:28)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.tools.native2ascii.Main
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:156)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:128)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.native2ascii.SunNative2Ascii.run(SunNative2Ascii.java:51)
... 22 more
 --- Nested Exception ---
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.tools.native2ascii.Main
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:156)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:128)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.native2ascii.SunNative2Ascii.run(SunNative2Ascii.java:51)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.native2ascii.DefaultNative2Ascii.convert(DefaultNative2Ascii.java:54)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Native2Ascii.convert(Native2Ascii.java:268)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Native2Ascii.execute(Native2Ascii.java:227)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure13.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:116)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure13.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:115)
at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp:28)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Error executing script RunApp: : Error starting Sun's native2ascii:
```

Comment: Too bad that the question is closed, because I had the same problem, and this solves it: http://grailslog.blogspot.com/2008/09/error-starting-suns-native2ascii-in.html